# Использование boost::bind() и shared_from_this()

Tags: c++, boost

В [примере](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html) асинхронного tcp-сервера на бусте связывается функция (все это происходит в классе, наследующим `enable_shared_from_this`):

```
boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
         boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
           boost::asio::placeholders::error,
           boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));  
...  
void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
       size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)   {   }
```

Почему при вызове `boost::bind(...)` в ее аргументы передается `shared_from_this()`? Какой в этом смысл, если все аргументы `boost::bind(...)` (кроме первого) должны использоваться как аргументы `handle_write(...)`, но в аргументах `handle_write(...)` нет никаких указателей на классы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handle_write` является функцией-членом, т.е. первым (неявным) параметром принимает указатель `this`. Этот `this`, правда уже в форме `shared_ptr`, а не обычного сырого указателя, связывается с помощью `bind` с `handle_write`.

Таким образом, можно сказать, что в `async_write` выполняется вызов вида:

```
shared_from_this()->handle_write( /*остальные параметры*/);
```

Наличие `shared_ptr` судя по всему требуется из-за асинхронного вызова, т.е. когда функция фактически может "пережить" объект, который она принимает  параметром через указатель.